# How bad is it to set password text

Tags: asp.net, security, passwords, save, user-input

For `<input type="password" />`

In ASP.net:

```
PasswordField.text = RawPasswordString;
```

This doesn't work, but can be circumvented with:

```
PasswordField.Attributes.Add("value", RawPasswordString);
```

I'm doing this so when the registration form fails, they don't need to re-enter their passwords if they were valid, this annoys me no end on some websites.  We have a CAPTCHA field that needs server validation, so when this fails (the most likely field to fail), I don't want them to enter a correct one, but then the passwords fail because they cleared, meaning they have to enter the CAPTCHA `again`.

What are the security reasons, and if this page is on HTTPS is that OK?  If it's on HTTPS with nocaching, what else should I be aware of?

Comment: If you are using HTTPS it makes it not as bad. The new issue is that passwords should be one way hashed. In other words you are not able to retrieve the raw password, if the user forgot it you have to reset it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely not. Browsers still can cache the result and someone can look at the cache and take the password.

Comment: Ah didn't think about caching, if I disable page caching is this ok?  I want to capture as many sign ups as possible, and on other sites I've gotten so frustrated I've given up before.

Comment: I still would advise against it.

Comment: Why not cancel the full post back and use something like jQuery Validation?

Comment: @Daniel, yep you are right, sorry I'm progressively enhancing it and probably am giving the disabled JS too much credence, I'll remove it thanks for the advice

Comment: @Daniel, ah now I remember why, it's because the registration form has RECAPTCHA on it, which needs the page to submit.  Users are most likely to fail this stage, but our site does suffer from spambots.  I don't want 10% of users failing it then having to re-enter password.

Comment: @TomGullen - even if you disable page caching, that doesn't ensure browsers won't cache. Some malware re-enables browser caching...Don't trust anything at the user end.

Comment: @Rory, if they had malware that did that, they are screwed anyway though right?  Even if I didn't save the password, the malware would be able to get at it anyway